# Can you target SDK 5.0 with base SDK 6.0 for iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, iphone-5

I've heard of Apple rejecting apps with an iPhone 5 launch image that are built with SDK 5.1.

Will Apple reject an app that is built with iOS SDK 6.0 and targets IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.0, and contains support for the iPhone 5? I would also build against armv7, not armv7s because of third party libraries, if it matters.

I know there are other similar questions on SO, but I haven't seen any that address this particular app store rejection concern.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you're simply trying to provide support for devices running iOS 5 and up while also taking advantage of iOS 6 and the larger display of the iPhone 5. It should not be grounds for rejection.